# Assign a HWND to an OpenCV named window

Tags: opencv, winapi, win32gui, highgui

I have a `win32` child window handle from a `win32` application and I want to draw my openCV stuff on that child window. Is there a way to set the `HWND` of an openCV named window. I only found a function `cvGetWindowHandle` to get the HWND of an already created named window, but not an equivalent one to set the HWND of a new named window.

Any pointers on how that could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just handle the drawing yourself? It's [quite simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617635/zoom-with-opencv-win32-c) (although you probably want to add double buffering there).

Comment: OpenCV creates its own HWND, you cannot assign your own. `cvGetWindowHandle()` gives you OpenCV's HWND. Try using `SetParent()` to make it a child of your own HWND.